# Add a word after the post url if it is within a specific category

Tags: functions

Normal status for articles URLS:

example.com/23423/
example.com/23412/

I want the article URL to become [example.com/23412/?video] only if it exists in a specific category.

For example I have 2 categories:

news
video

article for news cat = example.com/23423/
article for video cat = example.com/23423/?video

thank any way

Comment: `?video` isn't part of the URL but rather a `GET` parameter, are you sure you didn't mean `/video`? Why do you want the category permalink to appear at the end rather than the start?

Comment: @TomJNowell ,,, I want video links to be archived in google embedded with the word video

Comment: So you're changing the URL so that the word video appears on Google? Could you not use the meta tags etc to do that? You don't need to change the URL to change the title and descriptions that appear in search results. Google should pick up that the page is a video if you use all the appropriate tags such as opengraph tags etc, what you're trying to do here is unnecessary and the kind of manipulation they actively seek to penalise